# Geometry Nodes: How to get uniform thickness with Curve to Mesh?

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to use Geometry Nodes › Curve to Mesh to create thin curvy walls, and it seems that the thickness of the wall depends on the size (not scale) of the underlying curve. In this screenshot, both curves have a scale of 1.0, but one curve is thicker because it's larger.

[image: Curve to mesh]

Is there some way to keep the thickness the same for every curve? Thanks.

Comment: if you really want to know the reason (and we don't have to guess), pls provide blend file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different radius. You can do the following:

[image]

Also, then you apply scale for curves, open Adjust last operation <kbd>F9</kbd> and uncheck **Apply Properties**. This will keep curve radius at 1.

[image]

You can also clear curve radius in edit mode, by searching command (<kbd>F3</kbd>) **set curve radius**

Comment: This is the answer, thanks! It seems that the "Set Curve Radius" node also affects the height of the walls (on top of the quadrilateral dimensions), so I just manually set the radius on my curves.